# Are there any flights from Medan to Singkil?

Tags: airports, sumatra-indonesia

I'd like to go (again) to the Banyaks archipelago on July this year (2017). So does anybody know if there are flights between Medan and Singkil, or Medan and an island on Sumatra west coast ?
It existed 4 years ago, but two years ago, it has disappeared...
franck

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Medan/Singkil) shows light options between Medan and Singkil, but how would you be able to go to an island that no longer exists (has sunk beneath the waves)?

Comment: Dear Dorothy, having been two times to the Banyaks archipelago in the last five years, i can assure you that the islands are still affloat...

Answer (score 1):

[Lion Air](http://www.lionair.co.id/) has flights between Kuala Namu (KNO) airport in Medan to to Silangit Airport (DTB). [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Medan/Singkil) can also help you plan, as you make your way around.